# TypeError for predict_proba(np.array(test))

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, typeerror

```
model = LogisticRegression()
model = model.fit(X, y)
test_data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
test_prediction = model.predict_proba(np.array(test_data))
max = -1.0
res = 0
for i in range(test_prediction):
    if test_prediction[i]>max:
        max = test_prediction[i]
        res = i
if res==0:
    print('A')
elif res==1:
    print('B')
else:
    print('C')
```

Using the above python code I have to predict the probabilities of the 3 possible results (A, B, C).
The probabilities are saved in test_prediction and it can be printed as:

```
Output: [[ 0.82882588  0.08641236  0.08476175]]
```

But the remaining part gives an error:

```
for i in range(test_prediction):
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

I want to find the max probability and then display the event that is likely to occur the most (A/B/C).
How to go about this?

Comment: In the future please add some code that is reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with another solution:

```
for i in range(3):
    if np.take(test_prediction, i) > max:
        max = np.take(test_prediction, i)
        res = i
if res==0:
.....
```

This worked by accessing the index in test_prediction using [np.take](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.take.html)

But the solution specified by @Vivek_Kumar seems more correct and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [numpy.argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) which will directly give you the index of the largest value.

```
import numpy as np

#test_prediction is most probably np array only
pred = np.array(test_prediction)

classes_val = np.argmax(pred, axis=1)
for res in class_val:
    if res==0:
        print('A')
    elif res==1:
        print('B')
    else:
    print('C')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
predict_prob_df = pd.DataFrame(model.predict_proba(test_data))
max_prob = predict_prob_df.apply(max,axis = 1)
predicted_output = pd.DataFrame(model.predict(test_data))
```

Then you can concat them:

```
final_frame = pd.concat([max_prob,predicted_output],axis = 1)
```

This way you do not need to use the for loop, which was causing the error.

Comment: Didn't work cuz of my float values in actual program
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

The problem in using array in `range`

In this case you should use length of array `range(len(test_prediction))`

Also you may simplify your code:

```
import operator
#...
enum_predict = enumerate(test_prediction)
res = max(enum_predict, key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
```

`enumerate` convert array to list of tuples (index, item)

`key=operator.itemgetter(1)` - max function will compare types by second value

Comment: Didn't work cuz of my float values in actual program
TypeError: ("'numpy.float64' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 0')